# get javascript var from iframe and place in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I got the following code:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
     title of page goes here
  </div>
</div>
<iframe src='sameserver.html'>
     <script>
          var pagetitle = 'page title';
     </script>
</iframe>
</body>
```

Now how can i get the javascript var placed inside the logo div?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you want to put `pagetitle` variable inside logo div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. You can do like this.

```
parent.document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML=pagetitle;
```

Comment: why would you use `parent` here?

Comment: I place that code in the parent right? after the iframe is loaded?
someid would be the id of the iframe?

Comment: How would the above javascript look like in jquery?
Or is the above also possible with jquery append?

Comment: $('#someid', window.parent.document).html(pagetitle);

Comment: or if it has some class then.  
$('.someid', window.parent.document).html(pagetitle);

Answer (score 3):

Ad `ID` to your logo, wait for `iFrame` to load and put variable to `#logo`

```
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo" id="logo">
     title of page goes here
  </div>
</div>
<iframe src="sameserver.html" name="myIFrame"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myIFrame.onload = function (){
        title = window.myIFrame.pagetitle;
        document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML = title;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

and `sameserver.html`:

```
<script>
    var pagetitle = 'page title';
</script>
```

Comment: ahh, c'mon .. the iframe contents where for eyes only, iframe contents should be in a separate file. I've modified.

Comment: Awesome solution! Just what i needed.
Tnx Mihai lorga